# Add non-Google login option to Flickr account

Tags: authentication, flickr

I signed up to Flickr using my Google account. This has become a major usability headache since I moved to China: While Flickr itself is not blocked here, Google's authentication redirect dance (which lately even includes YouTube) very often requires a VPN. In addition to that, Yahoo's login page dropped the Facebook and Google login options for users located in China. They still work, but you have to play with the URL to override geolocation with another locale.

How can I associate another login method to my existing Flickr account?

<sub>I am willing to create a Yahoo account for this purpose.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Flickr seems to run on the Yahoo! profile system.

Once you get yourself logged in, in Flickr's title bar on the far right is a button to open a user presence menu.

Open Settings, and on the bottom of the Personal Information tab you'll see Yahoo account options, one of which will be the ability to associate your Flickr account with a different Yahoo account.

Opening that option, you'll see the ability to create a new Yahoo account. Running through this process will let you create a new Yahoo account to associate with your Flickr account, and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook works. Though using that method would require a Yahoo! account.
Using Facebook to create an account on Yahoo!, then using that Yahoo! account for Flickr